# Rebuild .jar file for netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have a java project (Netbeans platforms and hibernate for ORM).i use hibernate build entities and add this jar file to my project and it work fine, When I add new table to Database and rebuild entities, it has error. the new entities class is not found though I have checked my code, but I don't find any solutions. Please help me(my table name is menu)

this i my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < table_row; i++) {
                Menu menus = (Menu) items.get(i);
                objectData[i][0] = menus.getId();
                objectData[i][1] = menus.getTitle();
                objectData[i][2] = menus.getLevel();
                objectData[i][3] = menus.getParentId();
                objectData[i][4] = menus.getClassname();
                objectData[i][5] = menus.getCategoryId();
                objectData[i][6] = menus.getIcon();
                objectData[i][7] = menus.getOrder();
                objectData[i][8] = menus.getCreated();
                objectData[i][9] = menus.getModified();
            }
```

and this is exception

```
Classes: loaded=3871 total loaded=3871 unloaded 0
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 4,074,373,120
INFO [null]: Total physical memory 4,074,373,120
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.osstech.dbentities.Menu
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.osstech.dbentities.Menu starting from ModuleCL@302d6b3[com.osstech.Systems] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@759d36f1[com.osstech.dbentities]] and declared parents [ModuleCL@7f28abd9[org.netbeans.modules.settings], ModuleCL@fcd0400[org.openide.windows], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@6db17b38, ModuleCL@561ac555[org.netbeans.api.progress], ModuleCL@52b4e7ec[com.osstech.DataAccess], ModuleCL@759d36f1[com.osstech.dbentities], ModuleCL@2716630b[com.osstech.wraplibrary], ModuleCL@6461d2bf[com.osstech.Utilities], ModuleCL@f27bf78[org.openide.awt]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/osstech/dbentities/Menu
```

Answer (score 0):

Need some code to say anything conclusively. But, seems like you have a menu configured in layer.xml called `com.osstech.dbentities.Menu`. That is mis-configured. when netbeans tries to instanciate this object, it can't find it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ShaggyInjun. i was fix it. I think this problem is cache of netbeans and I solved by solution: after rebuild entities i copy jar file to new location and add to library    of project.